# Google Spreadsheet. Run a script if "security code" is given

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to know if there is a way to run a script if a correct "security code" is given.

I have a script that deletes all data from a spreadsheet, I´ve figured that part out. I have this script running if user confirm the Browser.msgbox:

```
var result = Browser.msgBox(
'Please confirm',
'Are you sure you want to continue?',
Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
```

If user confirms, the script that deletes all data will run, else, nothing.

So, as an extra security step I was thinking about a "security code". If player confirms the Browser.msgBox, then ask for a "security code", if the correct "security code" is given, then delete all data, if not, msg: 'Incorrect Code'. Do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at inputBox. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox(String) 
And use it to compare with your generated (or fixed) confirmation code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer!

By any chance do you know how can I import a data table from, let say, this page: http://www.ipligence.com/iplocation#results

What I would like to get is all the table of results. I've tried with the =importhtml and =importxml, but... no luck. 

Thanks for any help.

Comment: unrelated to this. please create a new s.o. question with the code you tried.